# Solid color backgrounds and text in Android TextView are showing up darker than what they should be

Tags: android, colors, textview

For example, if I set the background color to be #FF0000, I expect a bright red.  However, I'm getting a dark red.  If I set the background to #FFFFFF, I get gray instead of white.

I noticed that if I switch the theme for the application from dark to light, then all of the colors start showing up lighter than what I expect, so red goes to a washed out red, and black goes to gray.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

More info: here's my layout:

(I'm trying to change the background of the TextView from black to white when it's clicked.)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/wordList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the alpha channel. The colors are in the format #AARRGGBB where AA is the transparency. For bright opaque red you should try #FFFF0000.

Comment: This solution probably works, but usually the default value for this is FF anyway, strange. Maybe you have set the transparency somewhere else OP?

Comment: I think actually the bits you set for red are going to be used for transparency while the undefined ones for blue will be considered zero. This results in completely unexpected behavior.

Comment: That was it.  I was using integers to set the colors from code, as I had seen in an example. The example was using 0x30FFFFFF.  Obviously now that I know that you define opacity in the color code, the "30" was setting the opacity.  Derp.  Set it to 0xFFFFFFFF and all is well.